# How does one iterate through an np.zeros array in python, printing the columns one by one?

Tags: python, arrays, loops

I have an np.zeros array that has been appended in another loop that now looks like,

```
array([[ 0.,  0.],
   [ 4.,  4.],
   [ 0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.],
   [ 3.,  3.],
   [ 0.,  3.],
   [ 0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.]])
```

How can I create a loop that prints the first column, and then the next column?

I tried the following code,

```
for i in goalsfor[:,i]:
    print(goalsfor)
```

but the following error occurs.

```
IndexError: index 19 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 2
```

Also, is it possible to append an np.zero array by column?

Thank you!

Comment: Where did you set i to 19? Please provide some more code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your print:

```
for i in range(goalsfor.shape[1]):
    print(goalsfor[:,i])
```

and you can append by column with `np.column_stack`

Comment: Thank you very much! That solved that problem perfectly.

Comment: Do you also have an idea for how to solve my second data output problem?

Comment: you can't mingle topics like that. i don't know what aloc nor hloc are. you should reset that question to its original state and keep splitting your main problem into smaller ones